# How to achieve compatibility regarding auto layout constraints for iOS12.1 version

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, autolayout

My application has a 'Search Bar' inside a `UIView` named as 'Container for Search Bar' which is again placed under a Navigation Bar. On the `Interface Builder` auto layout `constraints` are set between the search bar and `UIView` as shown below:

1. First Item:  Search Bar.Top
   Relation:    Equal
   Second Item: Container for Search Bar.Top
   Constant:    0
   Priority:    1000
   Multiplier:  1
2. First Item:  Search Bar.Leading
   Relation:    Equal
   Second Item: Container for SearchBar.Leading
   Constant:    0
   Priority:    1000
   Multiplier:  1
3. First Item:  Search Bar.Trailing
   Relation:    Equal
   Second Item: Container for SearchBar.Trailing
   Constant:    0
   Priority:    1000
   Multiplier:  1

The 'Container for Search Bar' (UIView) is set with width: 480 and Height: 44. Autoresizing for `UIView` is set to stretch and position relatively in all directions. The search bar is also set with width: 480.

Until IOS 10 the `UIView` and Search Bar stretched relatively based on the screen resolution of the device. However for IOS 12.1 version 'Search bar' becomes invisible at runtime. When I have debugged and checked the sizes, widths of both `UIView` and its child 'Search Bar' are set to 0 at runtime. When auto-layout constraints are removed then only the search bar is visible but not stretching according to screen resolution.

Need help in solving this problem.

EDIT:
The UIView container is placed between back/forward buttons inside navigation bar. That's the reason the UIView container is set with 'Auto-Resizing' instead of setting auto layout constraints. As it is between two button items I think it can't be set with leading & trailing space constraints to its parent.

Answer (score 0):

> The 'Container for Search Bar' (UIView) is set with width: 480 and Height: 44. Autoresizing for 'UIView' is set to stretch and position relatively in all directions.

But its subview, the search bar, is pinned to it using autolayout. You can’t mix and match autolayout and autoresizing like that. Apply autolayout constraints to the container.

---

It seems this is your navigation item title view. That explains why this worked in iOS 10 and not in iOS 11. Title view must now use autolayout with internal width and height constraints to give it size. You won’t be able to size it dynamically any longer.

Comment: I have added more information in my post under 'EDIT' header regarding the reason why I have to use auto-resizing for container.

Comment: I stand by my answer. Everything you are doing with autoresizing can be achieved with autolayout. “As it is between two button items I think it can't be set with leading & trailing space constraints to its parent.” And I think it can.

Comment: I removed auto resizing on UIView container but it did not show up at runtime. Then I tried adding auto layout constraints on UIView container relative to Navigation bar on 'interface builder' by control-click on UIView and dragging to Navigation bar. But Navigation Bar is highlighting. I don't understand why I am not able to add auto layout constraint between UIView and Navigation Bar

Comment: There is no navigation bar. Use the Safe Area.

Comment: I didn't get. Can you explain clearly? My app design has a UINavigationBar and the UIView which serves as container for search bar is placed inside UINavigationBar only.

Comment: How? You cannot give a navigation bar a subview. Is this your navigation item title view perhaps?

Comment: Yes, the navigation bar has a navigation item (UINavigationItem) that contains back, UIView and forward buttons. So do we need to set auto layout constraints between UINavigationItem's title view and UIView (container for search bar)?

Comment: Yes, sorry, title view in iOS 11 and 12 must have fixed width and height internal constraints. You won’t be able to size it dynamically any longer. Sorry.